# C++ mesh array vector ostream

Tags: c++, vector, mesh, ostream

I'm having extreme difficulty troubleshooting this, I'd be grateful for any advice.
1. I am trying to create a mesh array. This should generate a vector of 50, 52, 54 56...100. In debugging I never see the vector increase beyond 50.
2. I am trying to print the mesh array. I cannot use ostream here because this is not a class. So even if I could get the vector working, I don't know how to print it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<double> MeshArray(double start, double end, double h)
{
    vector<double> mesh;
    mesh.reserve(100);
    for (double i = start; i <= end; i + h)
        mesh.push_back(i);
    return mesh;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> MA = MeshArray(50,100,2);
    cout << MA;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i + h`  should be `i += h`.  Also, you shouldn't use `double` as a loop counter.  You run the chance of your loop running an inconsistent number of times due to floating point inexactness.

Comment: `i + h` this statement doesn't do anything. Did you mean `i += h`

Comment: To print: `for (auto i : MA) cout << i << " ";`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Header.h"
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<double> MA = MeshArray(50, 100, 2);
    int size = MA.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << MA[i] << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some text describing why your solution is correct or explaining it.

Comment: cout << MA. can not make sense. You should use for interater. BTW, for header file.  i += h.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<double> MeshArray(double start, double end, double h)
{
    vector<double> mesh;
    mesh.reserve(100);
    for (double i = start; i <= end; i += h)
        mesh.push_back(i);
    return mesh;
}
```